# "unsupported_grant_type" when using Google's urlfetch to get an oauth token from PayPal. Using "requests" works

Tags: python, paypal, urlfetch

I've been trying (and failing miserably) to use google's urlfetch module (python within app engine's local server) to retrieve a token from paypal. It works as follows using the "requests" module *outside* of app engine:

```
    url = base + "/v1/oauth2/token"

    payload = {
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        }


    auth_encoded = APP_CLIENT_ID + ":" + APP_SECRET
    auth_encoded = base64.b64encode(auth_encoded)

    ##headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + auth_encoded}
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + auth_encoded}

    r = requests.post(url,headers=headers,params=payload)
    print r.text
```

... but I get this message when trying the same thing with urlfetch:

> {"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"Grant Type is NULL"}

... here's the code that I'm using:

```
    url = base + "/v1/oauth2/token"

    payload = {"grant_type": "client_credentials"}

    auth_encoded = APP_CLIENT_ID + ":" + APP_SECRET
    auth_encoded = base64.b64encode(auth_encoded)

    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + auth_encoded}

    result = urlfetch.fetch(
        url=url,
        method=urlfetch.POST,
        headers=headers,
        payload = payload
    )
```

... I've tried everything that I can think of. Should be a simple thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This API call is formatted as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` , not JSON.

Therefore:

```
payload = "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

or

```py
import urllib
payload = urllib.urlencode({"grant_type": "client_credentials"})
```